# Assign the output of a static method to a static variable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, static, static-methods

I am trying to initialize a static variable with the output of a static method before the constructor in Python

```
class CheckStatic:
    first_var = 1

    # All three approaches failed
    # second_var = self.generate_second_variable()
    # second_var = CheckStatic.generate_second_variable()
    # second_var = generate_second_variable()
    second_var = None # this works

    def __init__(self):
        self.var3 = 3
        if CheckStatic.second_var is None:  # a workaround
            CheckStatic.second_var = self.generate_second_variable()

    def __init__(self):
        self.var3 = 3

    @staticmethod
    def generate_second_variable():
        return 2

cS = CheckStatic()

print(CheckStatic.first_var, CheckStatic.second_var, cS.var3)
```

None of the three approaches worked. The `generate_second_variable()` method is rather slow. Clearly, I can use a workaround (see constructor), but is there a way to just call a static method to initialize a static variable before the constructor?

Comment: Why do you have two `__init__` definitions? The second definition supplants the first one.

Comment: Remove 2nd init and your code works.